# Android Studio remove files on local and remote repository

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

Accidentally commit `google-services.json` file and I want to remove it on both local and remote repo without breaking anything using latest Android Studio Arctic Fox. Will later add this file to `.gitignore` once done. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you remove this file and commit this removal?

git rm -f .../google-services.json

You may also want to check this https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/bamCgTDajkw/m/uVEJXjtiBwAJ)

Comment: @KamilJeglikowski I do not want to delete the file in my local device but rather remove it from local and remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to delete the file in my local device but rather remove it from local and remote repo.

Then:

```
git rm --cached google-services.json
echo google-services.json>../.gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Record google-services.json deletion, and ignores it"
git push
```

The file will still be present locally, because of the [`rm --cached`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached) option.

Comment: What if I already made some changes with `google-services.json` before, then execute these commands? Does my recent changes with the json file will be affected or nothing will be change with it?